# How to append a new value to the same key in the list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, json

I have a list of test-failures as shown below -

```
all_failures = [
            'test1/path/to/test1/log/failure_reason1',
            'test1/path/to/test1/log/failure_reason2',
            'test2/path/to/test2/log/failure_reason1',
            'test2/path/to/test2/log/failure_reason2',
            'test3/path/to/test3/log/failure_reason1',
            'test4/path/to/test4/log/failure_reason1',
        ]
```

I am trying to construct a JSON like object by parsing each failure in the list. So far, i have tried to write the following code -

```
for failure in all_failures:
    data = failure.split('/',1)
    test = data[0]
    failure_details_dict[test] = []

    data = '/' + data[1]
    data = data.rsplit('/', 1)

    test_details_dict['path'] = data[0] + '/'
    test_details_dict['reason'] = data[1]

    failure_details_dict[test].append(test_details_dict)

    test_details_dict = {}  

for key,value in failure_details_dict.items():
    print(key)
    print(value)
    print()
```

The output i am getting is -

```
test4
[{'reason': 'failure_reason1', 'path': '/path/to/test4/log/'}]

test3
[{'reason': 'failure_reason1', 'path': '/path/to/test3/log/'}]

test1
[{'reason': 'failure_reason2', 'path': '/path/to/test1/log/'}]

test2
[{'reason': 'failure_reason2', 'path': '/path/to/test2/log/'}]
```

whereas, the **expected output** is -

```
{
    "test1": [
                {
                    "path": "/path/to/test1/log/",
                    "reason": "failure_reason1" 
                },
                {
                    "path": "/path/to/test1/log/",
                    "reason": "failure_reason2"     
                }

            ],
    "test2": [
                {
                    "path": "/path/to/test2/log/",
                    "reason": "failure_reason1" 
                },
                {
                    "path": "/path/to/test2/log/",
                    "reason": "failure_reason2"     
                }
            ],
    "test3": [
                {
                    "path": "/path/to/test3/log/",
                    "reason": "failure_reason1" 
                },
            ],
    "test4": [
                {
                    "path": "/path/to/test4/log/",
                    "reason": "reason1" 
                },
            ]
}
```

As we can see, I have not been able to add the **second** *path* and *reason for failure* to the same key. Example - test1 and test2 have two reasons for failure.

Can someone please help to understand what i am missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Reason

You are overwriting to `failure_details_dict[test]` for every each loop.

---

## Solution

You should set list to it only once.

You have several options to do it.

- Non-pythonic way(**NOT RECOMMENDED**)

```py
if test not in failure_details_dict:
    failure_details_dict[test] = []
```

- Replace assignment to `dict.setdefault` call. This way doesn't affect other interactions with `failure_details_dict`

```py
failure_details_dict.setdefault(test, [])  # instead of failure_details_dict[test] = []
```

- Use `collections.defaultdict` instead of `dict`. This way will **AFFECT** other interactions with `failure_detilas_dict`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

failure_details_dict = defaultdict(list)  # instead of {}
```

---

## Example

And I have refactored your code:

```py
all_failures = [
    'test1/path/to/test1/log/failure_reason1',
    'test1/path/to/test1/log/failure_reason2',
    'test2/path/to/test2/log/failure_reason1',
    'test2/path/to/test2/log/failure_reason2',
    'test3/path/to/test3/log/failure_reason1',
    'test4/path/to/test4/log/failure_reason1',
]

failure_details_dict = {}

for failure in all_failures:
    key, *paths, reason = failure.split('/')
    failure_details_dict.setdefault(key, []).append({
        'path': f"/{'/'.join(paths)}/",
        'reason': reason,
    })

for key, value in failure_details_dict.items():
    print(key)
    print(value)
    print()
```

---

## Conclusion

- If you want a simple change, use `dict.setdefault` method.
- If you have multiple accesses to `failure_details_dict` and you want default value for each access, use `collection.defaultdict` class.

---

## Extra

> How can we modify the code so that 'path' key is copied only once and only multiple dictionaries with 'reason' key is created? In general, what would be the best way to store the data in JSON format?

You can reformat your JSON like:

```
{
  "test1": {
    "path": "/path/to/test1/log/",
    "reason": [
      "failure_reason1",
      "failure_reason2"
    ]
  },
  "test2": {
    "path": "/path/to/test2/log/",
    "reason": [
      "failure_reason1",
      "failure_reason2"
    ]
  },
  "test3": {
    "path": "/path/to/test3/log/",
    "reason": [
      "failure_reason1"
    ]
  },
  "test4": {
    "path": "/path/to/test4/log/",
    "reason": [
      "reason1"
    ]
  }
}
```

From code:

```py
all_failures = [
    'test1/path/to/test1/log/failure_reason1',
    'test1/path/to/test1/log/failure_reason2',
    'test2/path/to/test2/log/failure_reason1',
    'test2/path/to/test2/log/failure_reason2',
    'test3/path/to/test3/log/failure_reason1',
    'test4/path/to/test4/log/failure_reason1',
]

failure_details_dict = {}

for failure in all_failures:
    key, *paths, reason = failure.split('/')
    failure_details_dict.setdefault(key, {
        'path': f"/{'/'.join(paths)}/",
        'reason': [],
    })['reason'].append(reason)

for key, value in failure_details_dict.items():
    print(key)
    print(value)
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. How can we modify the code so that 'path' key is copied only once and only multiple dictionaries with 'reason' key is created? In general, what would be the best way to store the data in JSON format? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **regular expressions** to extract the information from your failure log file names. This can be simply achieved in the following way:

```
import re
import json

all_failures = [
            'test1/path/to/test1/log/failure_reason1',
            'test1/path/to/test1/log/failure_reason2',
            'test2/path/to/test2/log/failure_reason1',
            'test2/path/to/test2/log/failure_reason2',
            'test3/path/to/test3/log/failure_reason1',
            'test4/path/to/test4/log/failure_reason1',
        ]


info = dict()
for failure in all_failures:
    match = re.search(r"^(.*?)(/.*/)(.*)$", failure)

    details = dict()
    details["path"] = match.group(2)
    details["reason"] = match.group(3)

    if match.group(1) in info:
        info[match.group(1)].append(details)
    else:
        info[match.group(1)] = []
        info[match.group(1)].append(details)

print(json.dumps(info, indent=4))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
    "test1": [
        {
            "path": "/path/to/test1/log/",
            "reason": "failure_reason1"
        },
        {
            "path": "/path/to/test1/log/",
            "reason": "failure_reason2"
        }
    ],
    "test2": [
        {
            "path": "/path/to/test2/log/",
            "reason": "failure_reason1"
        },
        {
            "path": "/path/to/test2/log/",
            "reason": "failure_reason2"
        }
    ],
    "test3": [
        {
            "path": "/path/to/test3/log/",
            "reason": "failure_reason1"
        }
    ],
    "test4": [
        {
            "path": "/path/to/test4/log/",
            "reason": "failure_reason1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You may use `re.fullmatch` instead of `re.search` with anchors(`^`, `$`)

Comment: @Shubham - Thank you for your solution. How can we modify the code so that 'path' key is copied only once and only multiple dictionaries with 'reason' key is created? In general, what would be the best way to store the data in JSON format? Thanks.